# HighcharteR not showing path at level with drilldown

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm currently working on creating a drill-down plot using Highchart in R. I've been experimenting with the following example code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(
  name = c("Animals", "Fruits"),
  y = c(5, 2),
  drilldown = tolower(name)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   name        y drilldown
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1 Animals     5 animals  
#> 2 Fruits      2 fruits   

hc <- highchart() |>
  hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") |>
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") |>
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) |>
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      boderWidth = 0,
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
    )
  ) |>
  hc_add_series(
    data = df,
    type = "column",
    hcaes(name = name, y = y),
    name = "Things",
    colorByPoint = TRUE
  )

dfan <- data.frame(
  name = c("Cats", "Dogs", "Cows", "Sheep", "Pigs"),
  value = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 1)
)

dffru <- data.frame(
  name = c("Apple", "Organes"),
  value = c(4, 2)
)


dsan <- list_parse2(dfan)

dsfru <- list_parse2(dffru)

hc <- hc |>
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "animals",
        data = dsan
      ),
      list(
        id = "fruits",
        data = dsfru
      )
    )
  )

hc
```

Everything seems to be working correctly, except for one issue: I'm unable to display the drill-down path on the chart as desired.

Desired Result from this [example](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/reference/hc_drilldown.html) :

[image]

Actual Result:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the version of the javascript highcharts that is installed with your highcharter. The latest version of highcharter - `0.9.4` is using highcharts.js version `9.3.1`

On highcharts js doc site we see on [drilldown.drillUpButton](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.drillUpButton) that is deprecated from v `9.3.2` in favour of [drilldown.breadcrumbs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.breadcrumbs).

So, what we are seeing on a `0.9.4` version is the "drill up button", and what you want (and what is shown in the example page you linked to) is the "breadcrumbs".

How come then that the example page is using the breadcrumbs? Because there is a dev version of highcharter -- `0.9.4.9000` (see the [changelog](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/news/index.html#highcharter-0949000)), which indeed uses version `10.2.0` of the javascript highcharts library.

In `v0.9.4` there are no breadcrumbs, all you can do is disable the drill up button (`drillUpButton = NULL` in the `hc_drilldown` call). So the only solution is to update highcharter to the dev version.

There are multiple ways in which you may do that. I used

```R
library(devtools)
install_dev('highcharter')
```

It recommended that it would automatically update several other packages, including `dplyr`, which I accepted.

With this update, and no change to your code, the breadcrumbs appear as shown on the example page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was thinking about getting the same version as the example too. If there's no other option, I'm gonna do it.